# Hapi - how to access route scope from request object

Tags: hapi.js

I have a Hapi API, using JWT for authentication. My JWT's validate function works as

```
let validate = (decoded, request, callback) => {
  // decoded.permissions is an array of the users's permissions
```

My route is defined with a dynamic scope as follows;

```
path: "/{portalId}/somedata",
method: "POST",
config: {
  auth: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    scope: ['user-{params.portalId}']
  }
```

I want to restrict the call to only be allowed is the user's permissions array contains an item for 'user-1', but I don't know what to check against in my validate function.

Where in the request can I find the route's scope restriction for the current call?

Or, how else can I construct this scheme to work for what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I ended up solving it a different way

My route stayed the same but in the validation function I construct an array of scope string based on the decoded userId and then just add that to the scope

```
userPermissions: string[] = buildUserPermissions(userId);
// after they pass any checks
return callback(null, true, {scope: userPermissions, user: user} );
```